# Buttons not working on HAVIT HV-MS672

Tags: mouse

I just recently bough a new mouse called HAVIT HV-MS672(the Magic eagle gaming mouse).

My problem is that when I hold down Left click it doesn't work. The Mouse 4 button doesn't seem to work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your product might have a flaw in it.

This question is probably more for the fabricant than us, because it seems like there is a basic mouse function that doesn't work.